# Print function in python 3.4 does not print anything in the command window when running the code

Tags: python, sqlite, printing

I am relatively new at this.

I created a database table named tuturial.db and filled it with 30 row and 4 columns of data.

```
import sqlite3
import time
import datetime
import random


conn = sqlite3.connect('tutorial.bd')
c = conn.cursor()

def create_table():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stuffToPlot(unix REAL, Datestamp TEXT, keyword TEXT, value REAL)')

def data_entry():
    c.execute("INSERT INTO stuffToPlot VALUES(145123555, '2016-01-02', 'Python', 8)")
    conn.commit()
    c.close()
    conn.close()



def dynamic_data_entry():
    unix = time.time()
    date = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    keyword = 'Python'
    value = random.randrange(0,10)
    c.execute("INSERT INTO stuffToPlot (unix, datestamp, keyword, value) VALUES (?, ? , ?, ?)",
              (unix, date, keyword, value))
    conn.commit()
```

Now I am trying to print the whole selected data in rows

```
def read_from_db ():
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM stuffToPlot")
    for row in c.fetchall():
        print(row)

c.close()
conn.close()
```

When I run the code I do not get anything printed in the output window
I just get "press any key to continue"

I also noticed that when I put the mouse on the variable `row` it says `row<unknown type>` 
does that have anything to do with the problem?

I tried to print something else simple like

```
MMM = 45
print (MMM)
```

Then the print function works

I am not sure what I am missing here.

Anyone can help?

Really appreciated!

Comment: first try to print the length of `c.fetchall()`. if there is no length, your print function would never be invoked.

Comment: Thanks @PrakashPalnati @ShirishShukla
When I try this suggestion: 
`for row in c.fetchall(): print("Type: {}, Length: {}".format(type(row).__name__,len(row)))` 
it does not work. Even when I try to just print everything: 
`print(c.fetchall)`
it is still not working. I also noticed that when the mouse on `row` is says `row<unknown type>` does that have anything to do with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Print length of row as below, to ensure have data in table.

```
for row in c.fetchall():
    print("Type: {}, Length: {}".format(type(row).__name__,len(row)))
```

Comment: Thanks @PrakashPalnati
When I try this suggestion: 
`for row in c.fetchall(): print("Type: {}, Length: {}".format(type(row).__name__,len(row)))` 
it does not work. Even when I try to just print everything: 
`print(c.fetchall)`
it is still not work. I also noticed that when the mouse on `row` is says `row<unknown type>` does that have anything to do with the problem?